# how to replace the VALUES from SPARQL with the Builtin listContains from the general purpose rule engine

Tags: jena, jena-rules

In SPARQL, Data can be directly written in a graph pattern or added to a query using VALUES:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE {
    VALUES ?l {"no" "neg"}
    ?a delph:hasLemma ?l.
}
```

In Jena, I found the `listContains(?l, ?x)` in https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/index.html#RULEbuiltins. But how to use it? How to provide a list of values to check if a given object of a triple is in that list?

Answer (score -1):

`listContains` is not part of SPARQL.

`list:member` maybe what you are looking for.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-propfunc.html

```
PREFIX list: <http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/list#>
SELECT ...
WHERE {
    ?a delph:hasLemma ?l.
    { ?l list:member "no" } UNION { ?l list:member "neg" }
}
```

It is equivalent to

```
WHERE {
    ?a delph:hasLemma ?l .
    ?l list:member ?member 
    FILTER(?member IN ("no", "neg") )
}
```

or

```
WHERE {
    ?a delph:hasLemma ?l.
    VALUES ?member { "no"  "neg" }
    ?l list:member ?member
    
}
```

Comment: Not asking about SPARQL, but about the Jena rule